# Dbus Monitor for Windows

Tags: windows, dbus

Anyone know of a Dbus monitoring program for Windows? Specifically I am interested in being able to monitor/manipulate dbus signals of a remote target similarly to how you can with DFeet in Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if it helps you to track a better answer, but on Windows you have a port of "DBus" called [windbus](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus#Windows_port). It seems not active on its development, the Sourceforge page is [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/windbus/) one, and consulting the NEWS file it seems that last version is 1.2.1 from April, 2008. Prior to that, the closest thing of DBus you can have on Windows is [COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model). On Linux you have the [dbus-monitor](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dbus-monitor) to "monitor", and as you pointed, D-feet to "manipulate". If you are interested on a practical solution, I would suggest stick with COM, if you really want check DBus on Windows, try to compile the port, and check with [John Palmieri](http://live.gnome.org/JohnPalmieri) (D-feet developer) how feasible it is to run D-feet on Windows.

Comment: I do not actively need this at the moment, but if I do need it in the future, I will see if I can work D-Feet into running on Windows.

Comment: @BasedAsFunk if you end up using D-feet on Windows, and if it is possible, drop me a line with your results. I do not use Windows, but I am interested on what are the outcomes.